# Initialization behavior of class members of primitive type

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17

I know there are quite a few answered questions here about this topic but I couldn't find one that fully answered my question.

Below I'm making some assumptions based on my understanding of initialization (as of C++17). It would be nice if someone could point out / correct my errors.

Given the type

```
struct A
{
    int x;  
};
```

creating a local variable doesn't initialize the object at all

```
A a;  // a.x is indeterminate, accessing it is UB
```

However, we can enforce aggregate initialization by the following

```
A a{};
A a = {};
```

which initializes `a.x` to `0`.

Now, given the type

```
struct B
{
    int x;
    std::string s;
};
```

creating a local variable default initializes the object

```
B b;
```

which results in `b.s` being default initialized (because it's a non-POD) but `b.x` being indeterminate, accessing it is still UB.

Next, we have

```
struct C
{
    int x = 0;
    std::string s;
};
```

creating a local variable default initializes the object

```
C c;
```

which results in `C.s` being default initialized (because it's a non-POD) and `c.x` being copy initialized, the behavior is well defined.

Finally, lets compare some types and check, whether they have identical initialization behavior. I'm assuming there is no difference between those types if I create a (default initialized) local variable (`A a;`).

#### Case A

```
struct A1
{
    int x;  
};

struct A2
{
    A2() { }
    int x;  
};

struct A3
{
    A3() = default;
    int x;  
};
```

`x` is never initialized, it's value is indeterminate.

#### Case B

```
struct B1
{
    int x{};
};

struct B2
{
    B2() : x{} { }
    int x;  
};

struct B3
{
    B3() = default;
    int x = 0;  
};
```

`x` is always initialized, it's value is `0`.

#### Case C

```
struct C1
{
    int x;
    std::string s;
};

struct C2
{
    C2() { }
    int x;
    std::string s;
};

struct C3
{
    C3() = default;
    int x;
    std::string s;
};
```

`s` is always default initialized, but `x` is never initialized, its value is indeterminate.

Are those statements correct and if not, where are the errors and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: Your hypotheses is correct.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If the type has a constructor, no work is needed, the constructor does it.  If not, nothing will be done for you and you either specify a value or get an indeterminate one.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica *"If the type has a constructor, no work is needed"* doesn't that contradict case C? And does that mean that PODs have no constructor at all (not even an implicitly generated one)?

Comment: *doesn't that contradict case C* Yes, but on could argue that `C` has a flawed constructor since it isn't doing "the right thing".   POD's do have a implicitly generated constructor that does nothing. This is why it is a rule of thumb, not "the law".  POD's are an exception be cause they are a class, but we want to treat them like a primitive.

Comment: @Timo: What is a POD? The moment you put a `std::string` in there, it stopped being a POD. You seem to be talking about an aggregate.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm talking about the members of those types. `int` is a POD, isn't it? It's just a coincident that `A` is also a POD.

Comment: (1) The concept of PODs is deprecated. In your question, what matters is that some of the types are trivially default constructible, and some are not. (2) Aggregate initialization is available for aggregates. Not every POD is an aggregate.

Comment: @Brian I fixed the question. With POD I was referring to primitive types.

Comment: `int` is a primitive type. In the absence of initial value, a primitive type's value is indeterminate. That's all there is to it, really. Aggregate or not, constructor or not, makes no difference.

Comment: @rustyx Afaik it's not that simple. If the object has static storage duration or is a global variable it gets zero initialized and this will set the value of primitives if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Of course it's not simple, it's C++, but your question is not about static storage duration.

Comment: @rustyx that's true. Your comment just read like you were generalizing so I wanted to check back.

Answer (score 1):

You missed just one subtlety: for `A3` or `C3`, writing `T3 t{};` or `T3()` **will** initialize `x` to 0 because a default constructor defaulted on its first declaration causes value initialization to zero-initialize the object [*and* default-initialize it](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#8.2).

Comment: Yes I didn't mention zero initialization on purpose, because of the explicit use of parentheses or braces. Because usually, one doesn't write `std::string s{};` or `std::vector<int> vec{};` instead of `std::string s;` or `std::vector<int> vec;`. I was specifically aiming for that syntax.

Comment: @Timo: For your first `A` you mentioned both, and things like `vector::resize` do value-initialization, so I thought it relevant.